# How to retrieve all archived cards on a board through the Trello API?

Tags: rest, trello

The following question was asked on the Trello API board.

I thought I'd add it here.

How can I obtain all archived cards on a board?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this through use of the [filter] option on the boards endpoint:

```
/1/boards/[boardId]/cards?filter=closed&key=[your appKey]
```

It's the `closed=true` part that does the trick.  It directs the API to only return cards which have been archived.  I'm fairly certain it includes cards in archived lists, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: This did the trick for me!! https://api.trello.com/1/boards/[boardid]/cards/closed?key=[apikey]

Comment: It appears the syntax may have changed a bit.  Neither of the above worked for me, but this did: `/1/boards/[boardId]/?cards=closed&key=[key]`

Comment: I've updated the answer IAW the [Trello docs](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-cards).

Comment: Still works at this date, but not visible in the Trello docs. As provided by @gregsdennis.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the previous answer, according to [this part of the Trello REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-boards/#api-boards-id-cards-filter-get), possible options for `filter` are: `all`, `closed`, `none`, `open` and `visible`.

So if anyone is looking for a way to get **all** cards, both archived and not archived, do

```sh
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{board}/cards?filter=all&key={key}&token={token}
# ---------------------------------------------------^^^
```

For only archived cards:

```sh
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{board}/cards?filter=closed&key={key}&token={token}
# ---------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```