# How can I only retrieve only the active checklists on a Trello board?

Tags: api, trello

Using the Trello API, making a request to `/1/boards/[board id]/checklists` appears to return a list of all checklists ever on that board. The API says you can pass the `cards` parameter in the URL to filter the results (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311237/217374), but passing `open` or `closed` doesn't appear to make a difference, and `visible` just tells me it's an invalid value for the filter.

Is it possible to just get the active checklists? Are the API docs wrong, or am I doing it wrong?